# Can I use opencv image erosion to erosion RGB under certain conditions?

Tags: python, opencv

I would like to use the default erosion code below to grab and draw a section of a particular rgb.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('j.png',0)
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
erosion = cv2.erode(img,kernel,iterations = 1)
```

For example, I want to erase the condition of RGB as below.

```
lower_red = np.array([30,150,50])
upper_red = np.array([255,255,180])
```

How do you write the code using cv2?(i guess it mat be using inrange)

https://pythonprogramming.net/morphological-transformation-python-opencv-tutorial/

I am looking at the code based on the video from the link above.